# GeoJSON shape distorted on Leaflet.js spherical mercator WMS map

Tags: openlayers-2, leaflet, wgs84, tilecache, epsg

I have a map with a simple **WMS** layer in spherical mercator projection (rendered by a OSM-Mapnik-TileCache server stack, everything is in **EPSG:900913 / EPSG:3857**).

First: I can't understand why, if Leaflet uses CRS **EPSG:3857**, whose unit is ***meters***, I still have to provide coordinates, like *maxBounds* and *center*, in WGS84 format, which is ***degrees***. Is it an API inconsistency?

Second: I need to render a **GeoJSON** feature expressed in WGS84 coordinates (**EPSG:4326**), but the shape is visibly distorted (see pics below). Should I ***convert*** the shape from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857? How? If I did so, I would have coordinates expressed in meters, while Leaflet still expects degrees!

*I made a double check with a simple wms layer in OpenLayers and a GeoJSON overlay and it works fine, so I proved that the distortion is not in the data.*

Any clue?

Here is the test GeoJSON, hope someone can understand the reason of the issue:

```
{
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
        [
            [14.740017498458682, 40.673078870109705],
            [14.740132563378529, 40.673283531348574],
            [14.741625561383819, 40.67246759585111],
            [14.741671820229074, 40.672308542443076],
            [14.74151049646397, 40.672262934612235],
            [14.740017498458682, 40.673078870109705]
        ]
    ]
}
```

GeoJSON feature on Leaflet map:
[image: snap 2014-03-13 at 18 19 02]

GeoJSON feature on OpenLayers map:
[image: snap 2014-03-13 at 18 18 48]

Comment: Does open layer expect the coordinates as LatLong instead of X Coordinate (i.e. Longitude) and Y coordinate (i.e. Latitude)?

Comment: There are multiple sub questions, and you'll get quicker help if you keep only one question per post. To Answer your main question, we'll need to know how your data should actually look. Can you post an image of that?

Comment: Thanks guys, it seems I actually solved the issue. The problem seems to be not in how Leaflet handles projections, but in my GeoJSON data. I managed to perform calculations in a CRS that best suits my needs (EPSG:3004), then projecting to EPSG:4326, and the shape now looks good.